# How to remove HTML checkboxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Have a set of checkboxes as such:

```
   <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
        <label id="test">
            <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" checked value="<?=$skill->name; ?>"> <?=$skill->name; ?>
        </label>
    </div>
   <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
        <label id="test">
            <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" checked value="<?=$skill->name; ?>"> <?=$skill->name; ?>
        </label>
    </div>
```

And i have the following JS

```
$('#test').on('click', null, function(){
    alert("Clicked");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

What i am trying is to remove individual checkboxes (with its label) when ever the user click on the label.

I would like to have something like this:

```
   <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
        <label id="test" onClick="removeMe()">
            <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" checked value="<?=$skill->name; ?>"> <?=$skill->name; ?>
        </label>
    </div>
```

And on my javascript:

```
function removeMe(){
// Do some AJAX GET/POST
$.ajax....

// and finally
$(this).remove() // i am not sure how to do this....
}
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks

## EDIT:

So this is the solution that i use:

```
function removeMe(object, skillId, personId){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: SOME_URL_GOES_HERE,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { skill_id: skillId, person_id: personId },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            noty({
                text: data.message,
                layout: 'topRight',
                type: data.response
            });
            $(object).remove();
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            noty({
                layout: 'topRight',
                text: 'Failed to delete record, please try again.',
                type: 'error'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And as suggested, i use .class instead of id for my .

Comment: Edit: comment before mine was deleted but the following is still true: you'll probably want to put the `remove` in the `complete` or `success` method of the `$.ajax` call. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You should **never** use the same ID for multiple elements.. The ID is unique. Use a class instead...

Comment: @CodeLღver I can only remove the first element, due to using the same ID for each element

Comment: @BrentWaggoner Yes, you are right. But i am still struggling on how to remove the element individually

Comment: @JeremyRIrawan give the class or other property instead of the id. you can check my answer also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your 1st code there is multiple label with same id.
There should be unique id for each element that's why you code is not working for 1st code. Give the class or other property instead of the id**

And for 2nd code, you should do this:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
   <label id="test" onClick="removeMe(this)"> <!--pass the object of current element-->
       <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" checked value="<?=$skill->name; ?>"> <?=$skill->name; ?>
   </label>
</div>
```

And your JS code:

```
function removeMe(that){
  // Do some AJAX GET/POST
  $.ajax....

  $(that).remove(); 
}
```

You need to pass the object in the function.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I have decided to use your answer. Although Jay's and Dhaval's also correct.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any inline JS to do this and you cannot have duplicate id's in your page. Remove the id's from the labels and then do this -

```
$('.icheck').on('change', function() { // captures the change of the checkbox
    $.ajax({
        // stuff..
    }).done(function() { // now that AJAX is done, remove the element
        $(this).closest('label').remove(); // removing the label removes the checkbox too
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, yours is also correct however i just have to accept Love's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with your code you need to pass `this` as a reference to your element where `this` refers to the element you've clicked

And you should remove your element after the ajax call so you can try [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-0) for the ajax completion

Your markup will be like this:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
    <label id="test" onClick="removeMe(this)"> <!-- added this -->
        <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" checked value="<?=$skill->name; ?>">
        <?=$skill->name; ?>
    </label>
</div>
```

So your code prototype should be like this

```
function removeMe(element) { // you will get element here passed as "this" to function call
    $.ajax(function() { 
         // Do some AJAX GET/POST 
     }).done(function() {
            //and finally
            $(element).remove(); // will remove element after ajax call
        });
    }
```

And a side note **IDs** must be **unique**

Answer (score 1):

Use `remove()` on `parent()`. here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7K3L)

```
 $(this).parent().remove();
```

Also, dont use same `ID` for multiple items, `ID` is meant to be unique. Hence updated a bit of `HTML`

Comment: Fix your link, bud. : )

Comment: @Casey Falk- Updated link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just inject `this` to function

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
    <label id="test" onClick="removeMe(this)">
        <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" checked value="<?=$skill->name; ?>"> <?=$skill->name; ?>
    </label>
</div>
```

And use it like this:

```
function removeMe(el){
  // Do some AJAX GET/POST
  $.ajax....

  // and finally
  el.remove() // i am not sure how to do this....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple fiddle, is this the behavior you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/a74L9/

HTML:

```
<div id="one" class ="chkbox">
   <label >
       <input type="checkbox" value='One' > AAA
   </label>
</div>
    <div id="two" class ="chkbox">
   <label >
       <input type="checkbox" value='two' > AAA1
   </label>
</div>
        <div id="three" class ="chkbox">
   <label >
       <input type="checkbox" value='three' > AAA2
   </label>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
 $(".chkbox").click(function(element){
    $(this).remove();
});
```